# Pass an Object Type variable inside a method and cast it to a specific class inside if statement

Tags: java

I pass an Object Type variable inside a method and i want to cast it to a specific class according to a flag (I am also passing the flag).

If I put the code inside the if - else statement it works, but i end up with duplicate code.

This is an existing project and I cannot mess with the objects.

```
public void insertReport(Object request , String requestJson , int reportFlag){
Object reportRequest;

if (reportFlag == 0 ) {
   reportRequest = (MonthlyCls) request;
}else{
   reportRequest = (DailyCls) request;
}

RepEntity repEntity = new RepEntity ();
repEntity.setId(reportRequest.getReportInfo().getId());
repEntity.setDate(newTimestamp(reportRequest.getReportInfo().getDate()));
```

Is there a way to make java "understands" the casting in compile time?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `instanceOf` check instead of passing a flag?

Comment: it also seems that the thing you want to achieve is only possible in switch expressions since java-12; that is no explicit `instanceOf` and _then_ a `cast`

Comment: Are `MonthlyCls` and `DailyCls` related in any way? Do they have a common ancestor?

Comment: No , unfortunately they do not have  common ancestor.
They are 2 objects with some of their field identical.
Tried instanceOf , didn't work unfortunately . And I am working in java 8.

Comment: And `reportRequest.getReportInfo()` compile ? Since both seems to have common methods, use an interface.

Comment: No, it does not compile as it is now. The main problem is that casting happens in runtime so , of course is does not find the methods. I tried generics too,  but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use an interface or an abstract class to have a common type.

```
public abstract class Request{
    public abstract ReportingInfo getReportInfo();
}
```

Then Extends the class in both classes, the methods should already be implemented.

```
public class DailyCls extends Request {

    public ReportingInfo(){ ... }
}

public class MonthlyCls extends Request {

    public ReportingInfo(){ ... }
}
```

You can also implement the method in `Request` if it is possible/necessary.

That way, you just have to change the signature to accept a `Request`

```
public void insertReport(Request request, String requestJson){
    RepEntity repEntity = new RepEntity ();
    repEntity.setId(request.getReportInfo().getId());
    repEntity.setDate(newTimestamp(request.getReportInfo().getDate()));
}
```

Comment: I cannot touch the classes themselves unfortunately. This would be a really nice solution, i thought it too.

Comment: @Filip123go Then use an interface, adding an interface to an existing class won't change the logic. From what you show, All you have to do is to add an `extends Request` (or equivalent for interface), the method is already implemented in the classes

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will talk to the person responsible and hope that they will let me make this simple change.

Comment: @Filip123go I have writen [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56273429/4391450) (it is too different to edit this one). Using reflection, it is dirty but doesn't requires any changes, so this could be working with an external library for example.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, even if you cast the object to either `MonthlyCls` or `DailyCls`, the variable `reportRequest` is of type `Object`, so casting that object will not do anything. In order to be able to "access" the specific methods of both classes, you need to write something like this:

```
public void insertReport(Object request , String requestJson , int reportFlag){
MonthlyCls reportRequestMonthly = null;
DailyCls reportRequestDaily = null;
if (reportFlag == 0 ) {
    reportRequestMonthly = (MonthlyCls) request;
}else{
    reportRequestDaily = (DailyCls) request;
}
RepEntity repEntity = new RepEntity ();
if (reportRequestMonthly != null){
    repEntity.setId(reportRequestMonthly .getReportInfo().getId());
    repEntity.setDate(new Timestamp(reportRequestMonthly .getReportInfo().getDate()));
} else {
  repEntity.setId(reportRequestDaily .getReportInfo().getId());
  repEntity.setDate(new Timestamp(reportRequestDaily .getReportInfo().getDate()));
}
```

EDIT: I am assuming that both the objects are not related in any way by a SuperClass or anything, I suggest you do so and you also check with `instanceof` if the object given is correct.

Comment: thank you for your answer. This works. That is what I am using right now. I want to avoid it. (There are more than 2 set in the method).

Comment: I'm glad it works, but you should really follow some of the advices they are giving you in the comments, having them implement an interface or a common class really helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can update the classes existing, a solution would be to implement an adapter that would use the reflection to call the methods.

Something like this would be quite safe to use

```
class RequestAdapter{

    private Object request;

    public RequestAdapter(Object request){
        if(request == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The request can't be null");
        if(!isSupported(request)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type not supported : " + request.getClass().getName());

        this.request = request;
    }

    // call the method "getReportingInfo" by reflection on the object
    public ReportingInfo getReportingInfo(){
        try {
            return (ReportingInfo) request.getClass().getMethod("getReportingInfo").invoke(request);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                | SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    static Class<?>[] supportedType = {
        DailyCls.class,
        MonthlyCls.class
    };

    //Check if the type is supported, to prevent any mistake with the reflection call later.
    private boolean isSupported(Object request){
        for(Class<?> c : supportedType){
            if(c == request.getClass()){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }
    }
```

This is really not a clean solution, but if the method `public ReportingInfo getReportingInfo()` is defined in every class you add in the `supportedType` array. This would be quite safe.

Tested with :

```
public void insertReport(Object request){
    RepEntity repEntity = new RepEntity ();

    RequestAdapter adapter = new RequestAdapter(request);
    repEntity.setId(adapter.getReportInfo().getId());
    repEntity.setDate(newTimestamp(adapter.getReportInfo().getDate()));
}
```

If anything else than a `MonthlyCls` or `DailyCls` is pass to the method, you will get an `IllegalArgumentException` :

Like this : `new RequestAdapter("");`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type not supported : java.lang.String
```